# The execution plan for this query contains the Eager operator, which forces all dependent data to be materialized in main memory before proceeding

Tags: csv, neo4j, load, cypher, eager

I am running this code in Neo4j:

```
//Creates an edge labeled "Mentioned". 
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///datafile.csv" AS row 
MERGE (u:ChatItem {id: toInteger(row[0])}) 
MERGE (t:User {id: toInteger(row[1])})
MERGE (u)-[:Mentioned{timeStamp: toInteger(row[2])}]->(c) 
//userid, userid, timestamp
```

And I got this warning:
   **The execution plan for this query contains the Eager operator, which forces 
   all dependent data to be materialized in main memory before proceeding**

*Using LOAD CSV with a large data set in a query where the execution plan 
   contains the Eager operator could potentially consume a lot of memory and is 
   likely to not perform well. See the Neo4j Manual entry on the Eager operator 
   for more information and hints on how problems could be avoided.*

Here is an overview of the dataset:

```
6824,1847,1464235815.0
6865,789,1464239415.0
6906,518,1464243003.0
6934,240,1464243031.0
6968,1482,1464244803.0
6976,1792,1464244811.0
6983,767,1464244818.0
```

What does it mean and what can I do about it ?

Comment: Try the periodic commit - https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/using/#query-using-periodic-commit-hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are creating (or not) nodes and then creating (or not) a relationship between them.

Within a single Cypher statement, Neo4j has to isolate changes that affect matches further on, e.g. when you CREATE nodes with a label that are suddenly matched by a later MATCH or MERGE operation.

That's why you have an `eager` operation.

To avoid it, you can :

- Change the `MERGE` on the relationship to a `CREATE` (if it's possible)
- Have 2 scripts: one that creates the nodes, and one that will just create the relationship (MATCH, MATCH, MERGE query type)